# (Keras) Trying to load in saved optimizer weights that are in the form of an array, but keep running into issues

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I trained a model a long time ago and at the time, I couldn't save the model or the optimizer weights using any of the built in keras functions as it kept throwing errors, so I saved the weights as arrays.

Now that I'm trying to load it in again, I keep running into errors when loading in the optimizer weights. I'm 100% sure that I saved the weights correctly and that the model architecture is correct since I used
`my_model.optimizer.get_weights()`
to save the weights (although that line of code isn't working right now because it says "'Adam' object has no attribute 'get_weights'") and I basically copy-pasted the model architecture.

So first, I tried simply loading in the optimizer weights as is using

`my_model.optimizer.set_weights(saved_optimizer_weights)`

but I get the following error

"You are calling 'set_weights()' on an optimizer that has not yet been built. Please call 'optimizer.build(trainable_variables)' to create the optimizer weights before calling 'set_weights()'."

I thought 'trainable_variables' was referring to `my_model.trainable_variables`, so I ran

`my_model.optimizer.build(my_model.trainable_variables)`

and it worked. But then when I tried

`my_model.optimizer.set_weights(saved_optimizer_weights)`

again, I got the following error

"Optimizer variable v/top_conv/kernel_25469 has shape (1, 1, 352, 1408) not compatible with provided weight shape (1408,)."

I'm not really sure where to go from here.